# LibGDX - TiledMap Unit Scale

Tags: libgdx, tiled

I'm working on a 2D rpg-style game and I'm currently rewriting my game to get a more clean and structured code. Some thing that has been bugging me is that I have no idea how unit scales work with the `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer`, it's kind of like a "Hey it works, I don't know how, but it works" solution. Basically to scale my map up, since it's a pixel game I use

```
renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 4);
```

which seems completely wrong since I've seen other examples using things such as `1/32f`. However using that makes me unable to even find my map in game when moving the camera.

I've looked up on unit scales but I have a hard time grasping why and how I should use them and if they are really necessary. And by using the code above, which I'm guessing I use the wrong way, does that bring any problems?

Thanks in advance!